# How to use keybinds (custom made from c# form) when using another program?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a form where I have a [bind "f4" for pausing music](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aFmc.png). I can use the keybind but [only when I am using the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LehCE.png), when I am using another program, ie. Google Chrome,[and attempted to use f4 for pausing music, the program ignores my key's responds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xydNb.png).

How do I make my form respond to my keybinds while using another program?

Comment: Do you understand spanish? This link could help you https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101195/como-realizar-una-acci%C3%B3n-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-combinaci%C3%B3n-de-teclas-cuando-el-formulario

Comment: I would say you should not be taking over function keys like F4 which well may be defined in other programs when you do not have focus, e.g. F4 is defined in Windows File Explorer already, or is the most used shortcut key in Excel according to some.

Comment: I want to make easy keybinds for personal use, my current keyboard, you need to do "fn" + "f4" to pause, I'm trying to make a solution to that problem by just clicking f4 without the fn key.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there is a better solution now, but I always accomplished this using Win32's GetAsyncKeyState on a timer.  [Import code and Samples](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate)

Answer (score 0):

Normal key bindings are only going to trigger when your program has focus. Instead take a look at https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-register-a-global-hotkey-for-your-application-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with Keyboard Hooks. Unfortuantely the code for that is old native code. You have to go down to calling unmanaged code from your managed application.

I try to avoid using umanaged code whever possible, but for you it might be a option: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/